# Searching a text file and sending only numbers greater than a certain absolute value to text file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a text file that I am searching through that looks like:

> ksdf 0 0 -4
>
> as7d:S:asf 0 0 -4
>
> kc:S:cd3 0 0 -2
>
> asdk:S:s 0 0 6
>
> lasd:S:dd 0 0

At the moment my specific problem is when searching the file for the 1st and 4th tokens. If the 4th token is a number everything sends fine, but when the fourth token is blank (as on the 5th line in my example) the code simply doesn't work. You can see I want to return three asterisks when it finds a blank in the `%%B` variable.

NOTE: Thanks to the user, LotPings, I'm using the `findstr` command to grab only lines beginning with strings containing the substring `:S:` just to clarify why that's there. (Ie. line 1 in my example wouldn't be grabbed.)

I'm using:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /F "tokens=1,4" %%A in ('Findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" print.log') do (
set space="%%B"
if !space!=="" echo %%A ^*^*^* >> new.txt
)

exit
```

Comment: posted code works happily for me.

Comment: `>>new.txt (if "%%B"=="" (echo %%A ^*^*^*) else (echo %%A %%B))`

Comment: Why are you assigning the FOR metavariable to an environmental variable?

Comment: I had changed the ":S:" to something else accidentally, THAT was my issue! Thanks for looking anyways friends!

Comment: @Squashman I am ultimately going to compare the values stored in `%%b` by using `set space=!space:-=!` to remove the negative, then use `if !errorlevel!==0` on that as a switch to compare the absolute values (one case to add the negative back on and one to echo the `space` value as is if it's a positive) to a static number like `if !space! GTR 3 echo %%a -!space! >>new.txt` if its negative. It hasn't worked for me yet, but maybe I'm missing something obvious, idk.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

>new.txt (
  For /F "tokens=1,4" %%A in ('Findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" print.log') do (
    set "space=%%B"
    if "!space!"=="" (echo %%A ^*^*^*) else (echo %%A %%B)
  )
)

type new.txt
pause
```