# Compare the absolute value of a number in a for loop to determine if it's to be used?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I'm now on the bigger problem I mentioned in this post...[Searching a text file and sending only numbers greater than a certain absolute value to text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637365/searching-a-text-file-and-sending-only-numbers-greater-than-a-certain-absolute-v?noredirect=1#comment72405317_42637365)

I figured if I `set num=!num:-=!` with an original value of, say, `-17`, then the `!errorlevel!` will evaluate to true or `0` right? Something's not working here though...

To clarify, I need to filter out only the first and fourth tokens of lines in which the fourth token is either greater than 3 or less than -3, as well as any lines that do not have a 4th token (this part is solved).  I have tried using the `/A` option of set and it doesnt seem to work still.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "min=-"

for /f "tokens=1,4" %%a in ('findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" print.log') do (
    if %%b=="" (echo %%a ^*^*^* >>new.txt) else (
        set num="%%b"
        set num=!num:-=!
        if !errorlevel!==0 (
            if !num! GTR 3 echo %%a !min!!num! >> new.txt
        ) else (
            if !num! GTR 3 echo %%a !num! >> new.txt
        )
    )
)

exit /b
```

The text in `print.log` looks like:

> ksdf 0 0 -4
>
> as7d:S:asf 0 0 -4
>
> kc:S:cd3 0 0 -2
>
> asdk:S:s 0 0 6
>
> lasd:S:dd 0 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"new.txt" (
        for /f "tokens=1,4" %%a in ('
            findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" print.log
        ') do if "%%~b"=="" (echo %%a ***) else (
            set "print=1" 
            if %%b lss 4 if %%b gtr -4 set "print="
            if defined print echo %%a %%b
        )
    )
```

Instead of printing when the value is lower than -3 OR greater than 3, it does not print when the value is lower than 4 AND greater than -4

```
-6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
          ^.................^
              don't print
```

Comment: I really like this approach. Elegant! Thanks @MC ND!

Answer (score 0):

```
set /A num=%%b
set num=!num:-=!
```

This establishes `num` as the arithmetic value of `%%b`. Note that environment variables are **always** strings. The assignment does the conversion each way as required. Your assignment would have assigned a value of (eg) `"-4"` (including the quotes)

The second command uses the *string* in `num` and changes all `-` to `*nothing*` hence calculating the absolte-value assuming it's of the appropriate `-number` structure.

Beyond that, I've no idea what your intentions are to create your output, since you;ve not indicated what the output should be. Either way, `errorlevel` won't be affected by the`set` AFAIAA.

Note that `%%b` will still contain the original number read at the point you are using `echo`. You can perform an `if` on `%%b` as well as on `!num!` - and use `%%b` or `!num!` in your `echo` as required.

You don't say what your `gtr 3` business is designed to do...

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42639932.txt"
FOR /f "tokens=1,4" %%a IN ('findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" "%filename1%"') DO (
 if "%%b"=="" (echo %%a ^*^*^*) else (
  set num=%%b
  set num=!num:-=!
  if !num! GTR 3 (echo %%a %%b 
  ) else (
  ECHO just FOR demo %%a %%b
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42639932.txt` containing your data + extras for my testing.

For each line that passes the `findstr` filter, if column4 is missing, produce asterisks else set `num` to the value in `%%b`, and remove any `-` from it. If the resultant number is >3, echo the original `%%b` otherwise - well, I've produced a report line for completeness. Obviously, that can be `rem`med out.

Comment: Just as an academic exercise, it's also possible to get the absolute value of a numeral with [bitwise operations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12041874/1683264).  `set /a "x = %%~b, mask = x >> 31, x = (x ^ mask) - mask"`

Comment: @Magoo Ive updated my post to clarify my aims. Essentially i want to just grab tokens 1 and 4 from all lines that have a value less than -3 or greater than 3 in the 4th token and send to a file. The /a option doesnt seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "threshold=3"
>new.txt (
    for /f "tokens=1,4" %%a in ('findstr /b /r /c:"[^ ]*:S:" print.log') do (
        if "%%b"=="" (
            echo %%a ^*^*^*
        ) else (
            set /A num=%%b
            if !num! GEQ 0 (
                set "min="
            ) else (
                set "num=!num:-=!"
                set "min=-"
            )
            if !num! GTR %threshold% echo %%a !min!!num!
        )
    )
)
```